# Call a function on change of a select option in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown (Select, option), and the options get populated dynamically using `ng-repeat`. I want to call a function within `$scope` on change of the option. Here is the HTML

```
<div class="type-style" ng-show="accountCount > 3">
     <select class="account-filter">
          <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"></option>
     </select>
</div>
```

I know we can use `ng-change`, but `ng-change` needs `ng-model` and I don't think `ng-model` is needed in my case. Can anyone help?

As you can notice in the code, I am doing and ng-repeat on option tag. So will I get that 'account' which I have used in ng-repeat, in the select tag? So that I can use it in ng-model?

Also, each account is a string that has 3 values separated by a '|'. When I call a function on ng-change, I want to pass the 2nd value with it.

For eg: Each account has Name | number | number2. Now in ng-repeat I am just showing name, as you can see I have done a split in ng-bind. So if I use ng-model in select tag, I will just get name. But I want number to be passed as parameter in the function.

Comment: If you want to use value of your current selected option of dropdown in function then ng-model will help you. use ng-change along with ng-model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem in adding a `ng-model` because that will help you to use its value. For example:

```
<select class="account-filter" ng-change="customerSelected()" ng-model="selectedCustomer">
      <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index"
          ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)"
          ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"
          value="{{account}}"></option>
</select>
```

Now you can read the selected customer's value in your controller by simply `$scope.selectedCustomer`.

**Update**

After updating the question with more description, you have two option:

#### Option 1 (recommended)

You can write like this (although, you can achieve much of it in the HTML itself but it is cleaner to do in the controller):

```
$scope.customerSelected = function() {
     var selectedCustomer = $scope.selectedCustomer;
     if (!selectedCustomer) {
          alert("Please select a customer");
          return;
     }

     var secondId = selectedCustomer.split('|')[2];
     // You can directly put your main logic here but since you want to
     // call a separate method with passing the id
     $scope.doSomethingWithCustomer(secondId);
};

$scope.doSomethingWithCustomer = function(id) {
    // Your main logic here after selecting the customer
};
```

and modify your HTML as I described above:

```
<select class="account-filter" ng-change="customerSelected()" ng-model="selectedCustomer">
      <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index"
          ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)"
          ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"
          value="{{account}}"></option>
</select>
```

#### Option 2 (less cleaner)

```
$scope.doSomethingWithCustomer = function(id) {
    // Your main logic here after selecting the 2nd customer
};
```

and modify your HTML as:

```
<select class="account-filter" ng-model="selectedCustomer"
    ng-change="doSomethingWithCustomer(selectedCustomer.split('|')[2])">
      <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]" value="{{account}}"></option>
</select>
```

#### Option 3

If you want to achieve it without the `ng-model` and without jQuery then you can use a directive:

See a working example below.

```js
var a = angular.module("sa", [])

a.controller("foobar", function($scope) {
  $scope.getCustomerName = function() {
    return ['Foo', 'Bar'];
  };

  $scope.customerSelected = function() {
    console.log("I'm changed");
    alert("I'm changed");
  };
});

a.directive("changeMe", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      changeMe: '&'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {
      element.on("change", function() {
           $scope.changeMe();
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="foobar">
  <select class="account-filter" change-me="customerSelected()">
    <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I am adding some more information to my question. Do let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: `<select class="account-filter" ng-model="selectedCustomer"
    ng-change="customerSelected(selectedCustomer.split('|')[0])">
      <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"></option>
</select>`        In this code, the problem is that in ng-model itself I will get the already split value. Because I am already doing a split in ng-bind within the option tag.

Comment: I may be talking rubbish, but I thought that ng-model will just give you the selected value text. So if the dropdown value itself is name, which was split from name|Number|Number2, in ng-model also will I not get just name? i want Number.

Comment: Modified the answer. Just need to add `value="{{account}}"` into the `option` tag.

Comment: Bingo!! You hit the right spot. Thanks man. I just posted another question. Similar to this, but I think if I use that instead of this, it could be a good solution. Can you check?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `ng-change` in select, `ng-model` is required for `ng-change`

```
<select class="account-filter" ng-change="fnName()" ng-model="account">
     <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: 1 more thing. Do you notice the split in ng-bind? I am binding the 0th value of the split. Now on selection of any value, I want to send the 1st value of the split with the function. Any ideas?

Comment: I have added a few more details on the question. I think that will change the answer. Can you have a look please?

Comment: pass the account variable to that funtion, split the value in inside the function

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="type-style" ng-show="accountCount > 3">
     <select class="account-filter" id="detect_change">
          <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"></option>
     </select>
</div>
<script>
$('#detect_change').change(function() {
//change detect function
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use jquery for this man :) I want to do it the angular way.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use ng-change event

```js
<script>
            
            var myapp=angular.module("my_app",[]);
            
            myapp.controller("my_ctrl",function($scope){
                
                
                $scope.your_function=function(s){
                
                alert(s);
            }
            
    });
            
</script>
```

```html
<div ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_ctrl">

<div class="type-style" ng-show="accountCount > 3" >
     <select class="account-filter" ng-model="selected_model" ng-change="your_function({{selected_model}});">
          <option ng-repeat="account in getCustomerName() track by $index" ng-class="(account | limitTo: 18)" ng-bind="account.split('|')[0]"></option>
     </select>
</div>

</div>
```